# Changing the font size of legends in Seaborn Implot or FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I made some plots using Seaborn Implot and FacetGrid. I have formatted all the axes ticks and labels. However, the legends, which are taken from the hue parameter, appear too small. I have tried all ideas within my limited ability and nothing seems to be working so far. Does anyone know how to increase the legend's font size? Thanks for your help.

Below is an example code. The legend (hue) appears too small.

```
with plt.rc_context(dict(sns.axes_style("darkgrid"),
                         **sns.plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=1.8))):
    g10 = sns.lmplot(x="DI", y="DT", col="NL", hue="NL",
                 data=sb4, col_wrap=2, aspect=1, size=7, legend=True, legend_out=True, lowess=False, ci=None,
                 palette="Set1", markers=["o", "D", "x", "s", "o"], scatter_kws={'s':35}, line_kws={'color':'green'})
# Add title to FacetGrid multiple plots
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.94)
g10.fig.suptitle('Put Chart Title Here',
                 fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
# Set parameters
g10.set(xlim=(-20, 120))
g10.set(ylim=(-1, 4))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-20, 120+20, 20))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1, 4+1, 1))
# Use more informative axis labels than are provided by default
g10.set_axis_labels('CDS', 'CDT')
g10.add_legend()
g10.set_titles(fontweight='bold', size=16)
sns.plt.show()
# Save the plot as image file
g10.savefig("output-10.png")
```

Comment: When I use the `plotting_context` decorator I get large text in the legend. I think you'll need to add a reproducible example (something we could copy, paste, and run) or at least show the image that you are getting. If you link to an external image hosting service, someone with enough points will embed the image in your post.

Comment: Thanks mwaskom, you are correct. Plotting_context decorator should give a large text in the legend. I spotted what the problem is. I realized that there is no need to add_legend a second time outside the Implot statement. So, I removed the g10.add_legend() line of code and everything works fine.